# Surprising node positioning in TikZ automata

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, automata

The following code (using the automata library in TikZ)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[state] (p0) {$p_0$};
       \node[state] (p1) [right = of p0]{$p_1$};
       \node[state] (q) [above right = 1 and 0.5 of p0]{$q$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

does not position the q node above the midpoint of p_0 and p_1, as I would like to.

1. Why is that?
2. How can I obtain the desired result referencing q from
       p_0?

Comment: Please, be so kind and extend your code sniped to complete small document (Minimal Working Example)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obtain desired position of `q` state relative to position of `p0` is not simple. The easiest way is calculate it as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[state] (p0) {$p_0$};
   \node[state] (p1) [right= of p0]{$p_1$};
   \node[state] (q)  [above= of $(p0)!0.5!(p1)$]{$q$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Regarding your code, it doesn't work as (may people) expected. In case, that nodes are rectangle, than the `q` node is `right=0.5 cm` from `p0.east` and `above=1 cm` from `p.north` (see illustration with blue line on image below). This is not the same at circle (see red line in illustration below). At it are considered coordinates of rectangle inside circle:

[image]

in above image I already consider, that the distance of circle had to be bigger for

```
d - 2^{1/2}*d
```

where *d = 2 r* is circle diameter:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{automata,calc,positioning}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm and 2cm, 
     rect node/.style={draw, minimum size=1cm},
     dash node/.style={draw=red, densely dashed, minimum size=0.707cm},
   every state/.style={minimum size=1cm}
   ]
   \node[rect node] (p0) {$p_0$};
   \node[rect node] (p1) [right= of p0]{$p_1$};
   \node[rect node] (q)  [above right= 1cm and 1cm of p0]{$q$};
   \draw[thick,blue] (p0.45) -| ++ (1,1);
%
   \node[state] (p0) {$p_0$};
   \node[state] (p1) [right= of p0]{$p_1$};
   \node[state] (q)  [above right= 1.293 cm and 1.293 cm of p0]{$q$};
   \draw[thick,red]  (p0.45) -| ++ (1.293,1.293);
% rectangle inside circle
   \node[dash node] {};
   \node[dash node,above right= 1.293 cm and 1.293 cm of p0] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

In above explanation I didn't bother with centering od node `q`. knowing what is going on the determinbation of corect distances that `q` node be centered should be simple.

But all this complication can be omited, if you rearrange node position as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}(1,1);
   \node[state] (p0) {$p_0$};
   \node[state] (q)  [above right=of p0]{$q$};
   \node[state] (p1) [below right=of  q]{$p_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives very similar result as is shown on the first image:

[image]

Hopefully, now I answer on your question :)

Comment: Thank you, your code works fine also for me. But, do you know why mine does not behave well?

Comment: @suitangi, see edit of my answer. hopefully it now answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

Use polar coordinates.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state] (p0) at (210:1) {$p_0$};
    \node[state] (p1) at (330:1) {$p_1$};
    \node[state] (q)  at ( 90:1) {$q$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]